# An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters Appium login page

Tags: java, appium, testautomationfx

I am new to Appium and have been trying to automate the App for Android. my all configuration successfully has done and now i am triying to login the App but at the login page i can not click Customer Number, password and login other than that i can click all objects above and below of the login page so could it be the Login Page is not clickable ? is there anyone faced with the same problem before?
I used any other locating strategy with xpath, class, id even I though if it could be a sync issue therefore i used also "wait" but the result always was same.

The error is : `An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.`

My code:

```
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = capabilities();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("com.oneandone.controlcenter.debug:id/activity_central_login_connection_mode_button_1")).click(); // this works right
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.id("login-form-user")).sendKeys("594636070");
driver.hideKeyboard();

WebDriverWait waitsecondtime = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
waitsecondtime.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Login-button")));
driver.findElement(By.id("Login-button")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

had this a lot before it's annoying it doesnt tell you which element it couldn't find but I have fixed it just by making sure the ids between the app and my code are correct using appium inspector.

These look suspect for ids. Ids are usually starting with com.something similar to your other one. And remember there are multiple types of ids in appium, but you'll need to call them explicitly in the by statement like ACCESSIBILITY_ID

```
By.id("login-form-user")
By.id("Login-button")
By.id("Login-button")
```